# Ratchet php websocket error

Tags: php

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:2000/' failed: Error in
>   connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Previously this connection at localhost port 2000 is working. When I restarted the browser it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command in the Terminal and then give it a try.

```
sudo kill -9 `sudo lsof -t -i:2000`
```

Answer (score 0):

- write the kill command for the port as per your PC OS.
- restart the localhost server and Apache server.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).